# What is the difference between $g \in C[a, b] $ and $g(x) \in [a, b]$? Also, what does $f \in C^2[a, b]$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis

$g \in C[a, b]$ and $g(x) \in [a, b]$

What is the difference between these?

Also, what does $f \in C^2[a, b]$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

$g\in C[a,b]$ means g is a continuous function with domain [a,b], while $g(x) \in [a,b]$ means that g is a function with range [a,b]

$g\in C^2[a,b]$ means that g is a function with domain [a,b] two time derivable (g' and g'' exist), and g'' is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The set $C[a,b]$ is the set of continuous (possibly complex)-valued functions defined on the interval $[a,b]$.  Therefore if $g$ is a member of this set we have that $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function.  On the other hand writing $g(x)\in[a,b]$ means that $g$ evaluated at $x$ (where $g$ can presumably be any function, continuous or not) attains it's value in the interval $[a,b]$.  Lastly the notation $C^2[a,b]$ stands for the set of all twice differentiable functions $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$.  Actually, does someone want to comment on whether we typically assume these functions to be real or complex-valued?

Comment: It totally depend on the context. It can even be with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ When there a risk of confusion, we write $C([a,b], \mathbb{R})$

Comment: In topology, I have also seen $C_X[a,b]$ to indicate that the codomain is the topological space $X$.